# Coding linear optimisation?

Tags: vba, optimization, solver

I am trying to identify the optimal solution on the below problem. Have tried using solver but without luck given the amount of variables. Thus, I hope someone can guide me on how to solve this with VBA or another solution.

Situation: I have

- 200 balls in 6 different colours
- The balls have been randomly assigned points between 1-1,000
- The balls have been randomly assigned a cost between 100-10,000

Problem: I need to purchase 11 balls that give the highest possible total number of aggregated points within the following constraints

Constraints:

- I need to purchase at least one ball of each colour
- I can maximum buy three balls of one colour
- I only have 15,000 of credits worth to purchase balls

How do I find the optimal selection of the 11 balls?

Thanks

Comment: https://opensolver.org/ may be a good candidate.

Comment: Optimize difficult; but is just using sql and vba to computer the answer for each set of 200 balls ok?

Comment: Each ball costs 100 to 10k, say an average of 5k. The credit is only 15k and 11 balls are needed, 11x5k=55k, 15k < 55k, this itself is problematic. When random generation passed the costs limit, then there is another constrained to overcome the ball color. So this has two stages to solve, the correct random generation and the application of solver. It might take a while to generate the correct random numbers. I tried to gen 50 balls only, with costs 1 to 100:  Got `points: 6382, ballcolors: [4, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6, 6, 6, 3, 1, 1], costs: 607` I use GA from https://github.com/remiomosowon/pyeasyga

Comment: You can also try the or-tools at https://github.com/google/or-tools